# how to push firestore data to algolia Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, algolia

I've been doing research for the last several hours finding out how to do full text search in iOS apps with Firestore. I eventually realized full-text search is not supported. I read up on Algolia, watched tutorials, read articles and still don't see a way to push data from Firestore to Algolia in Swift. Can somebody guide me to a post or maybe add like a code snippet or something to show me how I can use this software? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algolia offers SWIFT API client

> Swift API client is an open source, production-ready API wrapper that abstracts from the complexity of directly interfacing with the Algolia Search API

Basically to work with algolia using any API client, you have to do few things,

1. Install the algolia client

> https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/swift/?client=swift

2. Initialize the client with your application ID and KEY

> https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/instantiate-client-index/

3. Indexing your data & Setup searchable attributes

> https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/methods/indexing/
> https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/must-do/searchable-attributes/

4. Perform search

> https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/

Many sub-actions available within these to improve your experience with Algolia. I recommend you to go through the docs fully.

- Yes, there are few other ways available to work with `algolia`, like using `cloud functions` for indexing data into algolia and doing only search from your client. But as you specifically mentioned `SWIFT` the above references would help you to get started!

Comment: you can do full-text search from Firestore database in google cloud functions? @Muthu Thavamani

Comment: NO! I meant, we shall use `cloud functions` for indexing data into `algolia`. And client perform only `search` on those algolia indexes.

Comment: brother, have you used Algolia yourself? I've read the documentation, implemented the code, but I still have no luck. @Muthu Thavamani

Comment: Yes, I have integrated for one of my `Flutter` app, and it's working fine. have you checked your index data in algolia console? and have you setup the attributes you want to use for searching?

Comment: I finally got the indexing setup as well as InstantSearch but I'm having trouble doing one more thing, selecting the cell in the search results and having it instantiate a ViewController. I asked a question about it recently and was curious if you've maybe tried to implement that functionality as well. @Muthu Thavamani

Comment: Great! Sure, will check the new one!